# Problemas com Biblioteca Cielo e comunicação com Codeigniter

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, codeigniter

estou implementando a comunicação com os servidores Cielo para um sistema meu.

Porém, ao tentar carregar a biblioteca Cielo, me retorna um erro.
A estrutura de pastas está da seguinte maneira:

- third_party / Cielo / {arquivos da lib direto do git da cielo}
- controllers / Cielo_Homol.php { meu controlador de testes }

No controller `Cielo_Homol.php` tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH.'third_party/Cielo/Cielo.php';
require APPPATH.'third_party/Cielo/CieloException.php';
require APPPATH.'third_party/Cielo/Transaction.php';
require APPPATH.'third_party/Cielo/Holder.php';
require APPPATH.'third_party/Cielo/PaymentMethod.php';


use Cielo\Cielo;
use Cielo\CieloException;
use Cielo\Transaction;
use Cielo\Holder;
use Cielo\PaymentMethod;

class Cielo_Homol extends CI_Controller {

    private $mid = '1006993069';
    private $key = '25fbb99741c739dd84d7b06ec78c9bac718838630f30b112d033ce2e621b34f3';

    public function index(){
       $cielo = new Cielo($this->mid, $this->key, Cielo::TEST);
    }

}
```

Estou apena tentando executar o objeto para gerar erros e começar o preenchimento dos dados da requisição... MAS, e agora começa meus problemas, Está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Class 'Cielo\Merchant' not found
>
> Filename:
>   /Users/raphaelschubert/projetos/clientes/miPague/application/third_party/Cielo/Cielo.php
>
> Line Number: 59
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /Users/raphaelschubert/projetos/clientes/miPague/application/controllers/Cielo_Homol.php
>   Line: 23 Function: __construct
>
> File: /Users/raphaelschubert/projetos/clientes/miPague/index.php Line:
>   292 Function: require_once

o Cielo.php eu não mexi, está original igual à biblioteca disponibilizada no link do git da Cielo. [LINK PARA O ARQUIVO NO GITHUB AQUI](https://github.com/DeveloperCielo/Webservice-1.5-php/blob/master/src/Cielo/Cielo.php)

Será que alguém teria uma luz para me dar? Grato pela a ajuda...

Answer (score 0):

/Users/raphaelschubert/projetos/clientes/miPague/application/controllers/Cielo_Homol.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Cielo\Cielo;
use Cielo\CieloException;
use Cielo\Transaction;
use Cielo\Holder;
use Cielo\PaymentMethod;

class Cielo_Homol extends CI_Controller {

    private $mid = '1006993069';
    private $key = '25fbb99741c739dd84d7b06ec78c9bac718838630f30b112d033ce2e621b34f3';

    public function index(){
       $cielo = new Cielo($this->mid, $this->key, Cielo::TEST);
    }

}
```

/Users/raphaelschubert/projetos/clientes/miPague/index.php

```
// adicionar autoloader:
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

spl_autoload_register(function($classname) {
    if (strpos($classname, '\\') !== false) {
        // Namespaced Classes
        $classfile = (str_replace('\\', '/', $classname));

        if ($classname[0] !== '/') {
            $classfile = APPPATH . 'third_party/' . $classfile . '.php';
        }
        require($classfile);
    }
}, true, true);
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 *
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Comment: Obrigado! Agora a biblioteca está carregando... Mas agora retornou o seguinte erro: `Class 'Cielo\Cielo' not found`

Comment: pelo que eu entendi, na linha onde tem: código  `$cielo = new Cielo(...); ele não conseguiu fazer o Load da class`

Comment: ERRO COMPLETO: `An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Class 'Cielo\Cielo' not found

Filename: /Users/raphaelschubert/projetos/clientes/miPague/application/controllers/Cielo_Homol.php

Line Number: 16`